# Is every closure point of a convex set A also limit point of this set?

Tags: analysis

i was trying to prove the closure of a convex set A is also convex. I take two arbitrary points a and b from the closure of A , and i wonder that could I say that there should exist some sequences converging to a and b ?

i just learned that in a normed space the answer is yes. But why?

Comment: On what kind of space? In most reasonable situations, the closure of a convex set is also convex. When do convex set has isolated points?

Comment: On any normed vector space. when it is closed ?

Comment: the closure is by definition closed...

Comment: So in any closed set, every point is a limit point ?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: nope, is $0$ a limit point of the closed convex set $C = \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: Yes i think it should be

Comment: check your definition for limit point

Comment: But in the set {0} is there another chance for any point to be a limit point ?

Comment: discrete sets don't have limit points

Comment: thanks. Actually i was trying to prove the closure of a convex set A is also convex. I take two arbitrary points a and b from the closure of A , and i wonder that could I say that there should exist some sequences converging to a and b ?

Comment: on a normed space, yes. If you a different question, you should make a new post, or at least edit your post.

Comment: Thank you for everything! i edit my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be a convex subset of a normed vector space and $K$ its closure.
For $a,b\in K$ there exists sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ in $C$ with $a_n \to a$ and $b_n\to b$.
Then, for every $0<t<1$ it follows
$$ (1-t)a + tb = (1-t)\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n + t\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{(1-t)a_n + tb_n}_{\in C} \in K. $$
Thus, $K$ is convex.

As for the existence of the sequence $(a_n)$ in $C$ with limit $a\in K$.
By definition: For every $\epsilon = 1/n$ there exists some $a_n\in C$ with $\|a_n - a\| < \epsilon$. Thus, $a_n\to a$.